# How would the privacy of monero be affected by a quantum computer?

Tags: privacy, quantum-computing

So I was wondering, if say a quantum computer is ever made could it be used to break the privacy of past transactions?

Would that mean at that someone could just work though the blockchain and De-anonymize everyone who's used monero?

Comment: Ah I just noticed this is a duplicate -- original [here](http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-vulnerable-is-monero-to-quantum-computing?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Yep, using [Shor's algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9508027v2) for finding the discrete log would allow the person in possession of a quantum computer to find every `x` used in a key image `x.H(R)` (not immediately, but in a feasible amount of time), and hence know exactly which accounts are linked by transactions.

There's actually a bigger issue than deanonymising all the transactions if quantum computers become a reality in the near future though -- Schnorr signatures and EdDSA are both based on the hardness of the discrete logarithm problem, which means an adversarial actor with a quantum computer will be able to compute your private key from any signature you produce, and attempt to spend your funds before your transaction is accepted into a block, or some other similar attack :(